# How to Stop a second Thread running in the background

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dispatcher

I created an application that downloads a file every X time. I used a method that runs an Async task with a while loop until some signal is emitted by the user breaks the loop (Flag). I can stop the loop at any time but I noticed the second thread still run in the background (I believe). My conclusion comes from Visual Studio displaying the output as frequent as the X time I gave to the Task.Delay(X):

- The thread 0x8644 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
- The thread 0x7254 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
- The thread 0x9a14 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
- The thread 0x7558 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

This is after the loop was stopped. I analysed the behavior and the more I turn the auto download the more threads are used and the old ones kept active (I might be wrong). Can somebody explain what is happening behind the scene and if is possible to stop a Thread ones I break the Loop too.

```
// Task that runs every 2 seconds
public void Checker()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Flag)
            {
                Dispatcher.Thread.Suspend(); // This did not work, but you get the idea
                break;
            }

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
               // Do something in the UI thread
            });
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check cancellation token in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)

Comment: `Thread.Suspend()` is obsolete method

Comment: Eldar, thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: If you use a `CancellationToken` you can set `IsCancellationRequested` as Eldar mentioned. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

Comment: It is entirely natural that the threadpool will spin up and down the number of threads as workload changes. Do you *actually* have a problem? Or do you just *think* you might have a problem, due to those messages?

Comment: The `Task.Delay` has an overload that accepts a `CancellationToken` as argument, so you'll get the effect of cancellation instantly. Just make sure to catch the `OperationCanceledException`.